# Entity Framework : OrderBy while using Select extension method

Tags: entity-framework, select, sql-order-by

I have a search predicate as follows

```
{x => (x.Actions.Any(y => (y.Id == 1))}
```

and sorting expression as below

```
{x => x.Actions.Select(y => y.Id)}
```

But every time I try to run this code below I get an exception on the execution of the query (I am using Sql linq provider)

```
context.Employees.Where(x => (x.Actions.Any(y => (y.Id == 1))).OrderBy(x => x.Actions.Select(y => y.Id)).First();
```

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.

Does this mean that the `Select` extension method can't be used with `OrderBy` method?

Comment: what is the code you are actually trying to run? these pieces do not contain an order by clause.

Comment: I updated the post, please check.

Comment: `Any` returns single `bool`, hence can be used in `Where` condition. `Select` returns multiple values, how would you expect to `OrderBy` by multiple values? You have to select one of them, e.g. `Min`, `Max` etc.

Comment: My intent is to order employees by the Id of their Action, could you please explain what effect would Max and Min methods have on this query?

Comment: can you try .OrderBy(x => x.Actions.Min(y => y.Id))
You are trying to order a super-set by a collection of sub-set items (Actions) If an employee has 1 action, then it should be a reference rather than a collection. If an employee has a set of actions, then you need to sort by a specific action (the minimum, or maximum) not a collection, a whole collection of actions cannot be used as a sort condition.